# Hidding iframe if specific value?

Tags: php, wordpress, html, iframe, hide

I want to hide iframe if there is no `$content` present.

```
<div class="video">
    <iframe width="600px" height="400px" src="'.$content.'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\';"></iframe>
</div>
```

In my case if `$content` is not present, iframe loads `src="?autoplay=1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
<?php
    // Test if variable is set and has content in it
    if( isset($content) && $content != "") {
        echo '<div class="video"><iframe width="600px" height="400px" src="'.$content.'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\';"></iframe></div>'
    }
?>
```

This way the iframe will not be printed in the html in case of no content.